# json recursion handling can't solve two different scenarios

Tags: java, json, recursion

I'll post here a simplified scenario of my problem.

I've two JPA Entities with the usual bi-directional reference:

```
public class Customer {
   private Invoice invoices[];
   private String name; 
   private int age; 
}

public class Invoice {
   private Customer customer;
   private float amount;
}
```

Then I have two queries to be resolved by two different webservices:

1. List all the invoices over a certain amount, showing also the name
   of the customer.
2. List all the customers over a certain age, showing all their
   invoices.

For my first query, I would need serialization of the Invoice to include its Customer, but for the second query I would need serialization of the Customer to include its invoices. 
But all the documentation I've found is to stop serialization one way or the other, defined at compilation time.

Is there any way to solve this?